# urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused while CURL works

Tags: python, splunk, urlopen, connection-refused

I have a splunk custom webhook action.
The action python script seems to fail at this point

`Error sending webhook request: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>",`

Executing a CURL command for the same POST request works well though.

Why would Splunk complain with Connection Refused when I can connect to that same request via CURL? Any thoughts?

Ta!